# Number_format specific item in foreach php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Thanks for directing the link about the mySql API, i think there is a need to change to mySQLi or PDO. I have post the near-complete code below of same case, as my first time, could you please help what's error below, as it doesn't show the results as expected as the code using mysql_... please help. (assuming the select statement is correct please.)

```
<?php

$Ticker = htmlspecialchars($_GET["Ticker"]);
$StartDate = htmlspecialchars($_GET["StartDate"]);
$EndDate = htmlspecialchars($_GET["EndDate"]);

echo "<td>testing.</td>";
echo "</table>";
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=, ,);
$statement = $pdo->query("Select Ticker, xxx as 'Last Update',Price, xxx as TTlUndetAmt,
FROM trade
 WHERE Ticker = '$Ticker' and DATE(xxx) between '$StartDate' and '$EndDate'
 GROUP BY Ticker, date
 ORDER BY Ticker ASC, Date(ReleaseDT) DESC");
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//echo htmlentities($row['_message']);

echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    foreach ($row as $value) {

        if ($value === end($row)) {
            echo number_format($value);
        } else
        {
        echo $value . ",";
        }
    }
    echo " </td></tr> " . "\n";
    $i++;
}
```

?>

I got the results from select statement from mysql database. I use php to get the required data. I want specify the format only a specific item of each row to be numeric, i.e. (thousand separated). How could I do so? can below code do so?

Current output:

```
ticker1,2014-09-03 ,1.190,0,37247000
ticker2,2014-09-03 ,1.180,0,23246000
ticker3,2014-09-03 ,1.170,0,19188000
```

Expected Output:

```
ticker1,2014-09-03 ,1.190,0,37,247,000
ticker2,2014-09-03 ,1.180,0,23,246,000
ticker3,2014-09-03 ,1.170,0,19,188,000
```

The code I am using:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";

    foreach ($row as $value) {
        echo $value . ",";
        if ($value === $row[5]) {
            echo number_format($value);
        }
    }
    echo " </td></tr> " . "\n";
    $i++;
}

echo "</table>";
```

I found out that the above code will create duplicate role at the last row [5].

To my limited knowledge, I changed  to

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";

    foreach ($row as $value) {

        if ($value === end($row)) {
            echo number_format($value);
        } else
        {
        echo $value . ",";
        }
    }
    echo " </td></tr> " . "\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would incorporate the key. That way, you can just check for the field name:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";

    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo $value . ",";
        if ($key === 'YourFieldName') {
            echo number_format($value);
        }
    }
    echo " </td></tr> " . "\n";
    $i++;
}

echo "</table>";
```

The function `mysql_fetch_assoc` already returns a key/value array, so you don't need anything there. Note though, that `mysql_fetch_assoc` is part of an old and deprecated API. If you like, have a look at: [Choosing a MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Haha, seven seconds earlier to the same answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

I would bring in the names, and use a `$key=>$val` in your foreach as such:

```
foreach ($row as $key=>$value) 
{
    echo $value . ",";
    if ($key == "theRightColumn")  // guessing the column name
    {
        echo number_format($val);
    }
    else
    {
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the modification in this line

```
foreach ($row as $value) {
```

to

```
foreach ($row AS $key => $value) {
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer